# Can we able to view / debug the GRPC payload since its binary format?

Tags: grpc, payload, grpc-java

Like REST API we can able to debug the payload parameter with the help of browser. On the same way is there any tools / ways there to view the grpc payload info.

Comment: If you call toString() on the payload objects you can see what they are.  Additionally, you can install a ClientInterceptor or ServerInterceptor to print out all the messages.

Comment: Okay thanks @CarlMastrangelo